# change Dns server setting with client

Tags: sockets, powershell, dns, server

I am very new in socket programming.
I installed windows server 2008 and dns server on vmware.Now I want to change dns server settings via client with powershell.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm really not sure what are you trying to achieve, but since you mentioned Powershell. This is the code to set the DNS server settings for the Network Adapter. You have to run this in powershell.

```
$ifindex = (Get-NetAdapter -Name adaptername).ifIndex
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $ifindex -ServerAddresses "dns address"
```

Might be I misunderstood you?

Comment: i am very very confused about this could you please explain what's this code?where should I use it?this is my project and I don't where to start @4c74356b41

Comment: can I have your email address to explain the project to you? @4c74356b41

Comment: sure, spam[at]myusername.com ;)

Comment: excuse me ur mail has not shown correctly for me its like this: spam[at]myusername.com

Comment: excuse me ur mail has not shown correctly for me its like this: spam[at]myusername.com @4c74356b41